# Why does the wrong EJS tag cause this specific error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Tags: node.js, debugging, ejs

**Goal**: I am trying to understand an error which occurred while trying to render a list of "secrets" (strings passed from JSON objects) in a simple Node app serving EJS files.

**Code**

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/secrets", (req, res) => {
  const user1 = { "username": "jon", "secret": "blue blue blue"};
  const user2 = { "username": "paul", "secret": "red red red"};
  const users = [user1, user2];

  res.render("secrets", {usersWithSecrets: users});
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

secrets.ejs

```
<body>
<html>
    <h1>Secrets List:</h1>

    <%= usersWithSecrets.forEach((user) => { %>
        <p class="secret-text"><%=user.secret%></p>
    <%})%>
    <hr>

</body>
</html>
```

**Error**: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Sams\scode\Learning\Authentication_and_Redux\code\starting_code\Secrets-Starting_Code\views\secrets.ejs while compiling ejs`

I was able to fix the error by changing the 5th line of secrets.ejs to

```
    <% usersWithSecrets.forEach((user) => { %>
```

but I don't understand why I got the error that I did. I spent a very long time reviewing my code looking for a missing open parenthesis "(" before I even considered that the EJS tags were wrong. Admittedly I am a bit new to EJS, but this error was still very misleading.

Can someone please help me understand why this error was presented instead of an error stating that the EJS tags were wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because to EJS `<%= usersWithSecrets.forEach((user) => { %>` simply means to insert `usersWithSecrets.forEach((user) => {` in the `<body>` element. This is perfectly valid. EJS doesn't assume what you are wanting to do. In other words, that statement is no different than `<%= hello world! %>` and EJS will happily put that as the text in the `<body>` tag.

However, when you use the `<% %>` tag in `<% }) %>`, it tells EJS that everything here is a script and should be interpreted as javascript. Since there is only a closing bracket and parentheses and no valid javascript earlier to open these, there is now a syntax error. Changing the earlier from an output tag (`<%= %>`) to a script tag (`<% %>`) made it a valid javascript script with no error.

In short, just like the javascript interpreter can't assume your intentions, neither can the EJS parser. It couldn't possibly know that you were meaning to start a javascript script and not output `usersWithSecrets.forEach((user) => {` in the `<body>` tag. For more information on EJS [see the documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs)